# Flutter auto_router: Error: Type 'NavigatorState' not found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, code-generation

#### Problem summary

Hi, I have an issue getting the [`auto_route`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) package up and running in a Flutter project. Following the official documentation, I have done the following:

1. Created a placeholder class annotated with `@MaterialAutoRouter`
2. Ran the code generator (using `--enable-experiment=enhanced-enums`)
3. Hook up the router class with `MaterialApp`

Once I attempt to run the app with `flutter run`, this is the error message I'm given:

```
lib/app_router.gr.dart:16:26: Error: Type 'NavigatorState' not found.
  _$AppRouter([GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? navigatorKey]) : super(navigatorKey);
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/app_router.gr.dart:16:16: Error: Type 'GlobalKey' not found.
  _$AppRouter([GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? navigatorKey]) : super(navigatorKey);
               ^^^^^^^^^
lib/app_router.gr.dart:16:26: Error: 'NavigatorState' isn't a type.
  _$AppRouter([GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? navigatorKey]) : super(navigatorKey);
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/app_router.gr.dart:16:16: Error: 'GlobalKey' isn't a type.
  _$AppRouter([GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? navigatorKey]) : super(navigatorKey);
```

#### Additional information

The output of `flutter --version`:

```
Flutter 3.0.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ee4e09cce0 (3 days ago) • 2022-05-09 16:45:18 -0700
Engine • revision d1b9a6938a
Tools • Dart 2.17.0 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

Excerpt of `pubspec.yaml` file with relevant dependencies

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_route: ^4.0.1
 
dev_dependencies:
  auto_route_generator: ^4.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.10
```

#### Code & additional attempts

(1) Placeholder class (`app_router.dart`) annotated with `@MaterialAutoRouter`...

```dart
part 'app_router.gr.dart';

const authRoutes = AutoRoute(
  name: 'AuthRouter',
  path: '/',
  initial: true,
  page: LoginScreen,
);

@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: <AutoRoute>[authRoutes],
)
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {}
```

...and the autogenerated code of (2) `flutter pub run build_runner build --enable-experiment=enhanced-enums --delete-conflicting-outputs` command (`app_router.gr.dart`)

```dart
// **************************************************************************
// AutoRouteGenerator
// **************************************************************************

// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

// **************************************************************************
// AutoRouteGenerator
// **************************************************************************
//
// ignore_for_file: type=lint

part of 'app_router.dart';

class _$AppRouter extends RootStackRouter {
  _$AppRouter([GlobalKey<NavigatorState>? navigatorKey]) : super(navigatorKey);

  @override
  final Map<String, PageFactory> pagesMap = {
    AuthRouter.name: (routeData) {
      return MaterialPageX<dynamic>(
          routeData: routeData, child: const LoginScreen());
    }
  };

  @override
  List<RouteConfig> get routes => [RouteConfig(AuthRouter.name, path: '/')];
}

/// generated route for
/// [LoginScreen]
class AuthRouter extends PageRouteInfo<void> {
  const AuthRouter() : super(AuthRouter.name, path: '/');

  static const String name = 'AuthRouter';
}
```

Lastly, (3), this is how I hooked it up with the `MaterialApp`:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final AppRouter _router = AppRouter();

  App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerDelegate: _router.delegate(),
      routeInformationParser: _router.defaultRouteParser(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme.lightThemeData(context),
    );
  }
}
```

I have migrated to the Flutter 3 yesterday, and simultaneously started using enhanced enums as well. Without the `--enable-experiment=enhanced-enums` flag, the code generator doesn't seem to work. I have tried running the app (`flutter run`) with and without the same flag, but the aforementioned error persists.

If someone has any idea on what could have potentially gone wrong, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I have found a solution. It's trivial and caused by incomplete documentation. After browsing the `auto_route` GitHub issues page, I found [this](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/871), from December 1st, 2021.

The fix is to add

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

to the placeholder class (in my case, `app_router.dart`). Therefore,

```dart
// + other relevant imports
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

part 'app_router.gr.dart';

const authRoutes = AutoRoute(
  name: 'AuthRouter',
  path: '/',
  initial: true,
  page: LoginScreen,
);

@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: <AutoRoute>[authRoutes],
)
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {}
```

**Edit (March 16, 2022)**: as Yogi Arif Widodo pointed point in the comment below, you might wanna import both Material and Cupertino, should you need it

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```

Comment: nice ```import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';``` thankyou ...

Comment: You need to import all relevant file to your `app_router.dart`. Not only `material.dart` or `cupertino.dart`. In my case i need to parse a custom model `LoginModel` inside my screen. So i put `import 'package:project/src/model/login_model.dart'` inside my `app_route.dart`.